# How to download Angular 7?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am able to find this version of Angular js.
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js

I have read that version 7 is available now. The above version is 1.7 which seems to be very old as compared to 7.

I am learning Angular js.

Where can I download any new version of Angular js?

Comment: Angular v2 and up is **not the same as** AngularJS 1.x, the former JavaScript framework.

Comment: Go to https://docs.angularjs.org and you can see this notice:
_This site and all of its contents are referring to AngularJS (version 1.x), if you are looking for the latest Angular, please visit angular.io_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you navigate to: [docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org)
You could spot the notice:

> This site and all of its contents are referring to AngularJS (version
>   1.x), if you are looking for the latest Angular, please visit angular.io

To be short, AngularJS (1.x versions) is not Angular (even though Angular descends from AngularJS);

Not sure you're a web developer but nowdays in the javascript world the most of projects uses Nodejs and npm (package manager) to getting started projects. And Angular does too. So, in order to get latest angular, you could:

```
$ # from console
$ npm install -g @angular/cli
$ # creating a new angular project
$ ng new my-app
$ # running the app
$ cd my-app && ng serve --open
```

The official doc is a good place to start: https://angular.io/guide/setup-local